# JavaScript match files that contains certain prefix

Tags: javascript, regex, gulp, filenames, prefix

I have a gulp.src on a task but I want to match all the files that contain a certain word as a prefix e.g.:

```
gulp.src('./mydir/project.build-blessed1.css')
```

But there can be N files with different numbers, blessed1, blessed2, blessed3

How can I make it match any file that starts with that and has the .css extension on the same line, without using a function?

Comment: You need a glob pattern *Glob* which can wildcard match your patterns (search for glob or gulp-glob

Comment: Are we only matching files that match the pattern `./mydir/project.build-blessed#.css`?

Comment: Try lastIndexOf, https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_lastindexof.asp

Comment: you can get the files in a specific folder (where you put your css files) using this: `fs.readdir('./', function(err, files) {
  files.forEach(function(file) { /* DO SOMETHING HERE */ } }` and inside that structure you can check each file name with a simple regex or `includes()` or `endswith()` statement

Comment: Use Glob syntax https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob './mydir/project.build-blessed[1-3].css'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're not using an old implemetation of gulp you can use '*' as wild card even in the middle of a path so something like:

```
gulp.src('./mydir/project.build-blessed*.css')
```

should work

You can see the doc here https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md

Comment: That's right Sir, this was my first approach and it wasn't working until I've updated the gulp version. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As Splatten suggested, you could use string.lastIndexOf method. In your case:

```
var string = 'i want to do something!'

if (string.lastIndexOf('something') !== -1) {
    //keyword was found, meaning it's in the string
} else {
    //keyword was not found 
}
```

lastIndexOf returns the index where he found the keyword.